# IncompatibleClassChangeError when evaluating xpath expressions with namespace

Tags: java, xpath, websphere

i need to modify an xml document which has multiple namespaces. my code runs without problems on my local machine but i'm encountering java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when i deployed it to IBM Websphere application server.

i'm using xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar and xalan-2.7.0.jar.
what is causing this error and how do i resolve it? alternatively, are there other ways to modify xml documents with namespace support?

Code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(new java.io.FileInputStream("c:/test.xml"));

System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory", "org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl");
XPathFactory xf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xf.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());

// get the node for editing
String xpathExpr = ...
org.w3c.dom.Node n = (org.w3c.dom.Node)xpath.compile(xpathExpr).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE); // IncompatibleClassChangeError here
```

exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.JAXPPrefixResolver.getNamespaceForPrefix(JAXPPrefixResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.mapNSTokens(Lexer.java:587)
        at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:265)
        at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:96)
        at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:110)
        at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:176)
        at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:264)
        at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.compile(XPathImpl.java:394)
        at com.ibm._jsp._xml._jspService(_xml.java:94)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:87)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:592)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:232)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1037)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:644)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've managed to solve this. it was due to a class file (`javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext`) being loaded from the xml-apis.jar which i was also using.

`javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext` is an interface present in xml-apis.jar and JRE. in the JRE's version of the class, the interface methods are all marked 'abstract' but in the xml-apis.jar's version, the interface methods are not abstract. i believe this caused a binary compatibility issue resulting in the error that i encountered.

so resolve my problem, i changed my classloader configuration to use the parent classloader before the application classloader so that the `javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext` from the JRE is used.

Answer (score 2):

My usual rule-of-thumb is that IncompatibleClassChangeError means that the version of some class that was seen by the compiler at compile time is incompatible with the version of the same class that is loaded at run-time. The stack trace shows that the XPath engine is doing a callback to your NamespaceResolver, so that should focus the investigation.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that websphere has a copy of another version of xerces or xalan in a shared classpath and your application ends up using a mix of different versions. I would first try to find out which version is used by websphere and whether your application works with that.

If you are on Java 6 you could also try to use the [newInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) methods taking a classname and classloader and pass your webapps [context classloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader%28%29).